# Php Partial Caching

Tags: php, caching

I want caching some php files partially. for example

```
<?
echo "<h1>",$anyPerdefinedVarible,"</h1>";
echo "time at linux is: ";
// satrt not been catched section
echo date();
//end of partial cach
echo "<div>goodbye $footerVar</div>";
?>
```

So cached page should be like as
(cached.php)

```
<h1>This section is fixed today</h1>
<? echo date(); ?>
<div>goodbye please visit todays suggested website</div>
```

It may be done with templating but I want it directly. Because I want alternative solution.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Generating these lines will be faster, than fetching 2 keys from cache storage. Try to cache data from database, don't waste your time to output, it's template engine's business.

Comment: This code is only for example. Real codes are so complex and requires some sql queries. I try show my problem very clear. I want to know PHP caching mechanism.

Comment: Well, it's not only about PHP, it's common. Again: cache data, fetched from DB, don't cache output. And try to use Twig for templates, it will open your understanding of separation data from representation.

Comment: @OZ_ it is common case for all programming languages, but I know PHP lang better than others. I want use it for flexible templates. I need template that contains multiple parts that was created at different dates.

Comment: I don't understand what are you want to see as answer. It can not be code ready to use.

Comment: I need any function that calling it, stop caching and other function restart caching. also not cached codes should be add to cached file. For example `<? startcach();echo "some";stopCach();echo date();startcach(); echo "remains";?>` must be cached in files as: `some <? echo date(); ?> remains`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at php's ob_start(), it can buffer all output and save this.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Addition:
Look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php#106275 for the function you want :)
Edit:
Here a even simpeler version: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php#88212 :)

---

Here some simple, but effective, solution:

template.php

```
<?php
    echo '<p>Now is: <?php echo date("l, j F Y, H:i:s"); ?> and the weather is <strong><?php echo $weather; ?></strong></p>';
    echo "<p>Template is: " . date("l, j F Y, H:i:s") . "</p>";
    sleep(2); // wait for 2 seconds, as you can tell the difference then :-)
?>
```

actualpage.php

```
<?php    
    function get_include_contents($filename) {
        if (is_file($filename)) {
            ob_start();
            include $filename;
            return ob_get_clean();
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Variables
    $weather = "fine";

    // Evaluate the template (do NOT use user input in the template, look at php manual why)
    eval("?>" . get_include_contents("template.php"));
?>
```

You could save the contents of template.php or actualpage.php with http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php to some file, like cached.php. Then you can let the actualpage.php check the date of cached.php and if too old, let it make a new one or if young enough simply echo actualpage.php or re-evaluate template.php without rebuilding the template.

---

After comments, here to cache the template:

```
<?php    
    function get_include_contents($filename) {
        if (is_file($filename)) {
            ob_start();
            include $filename;
            return ob_get_clean();
        }
        return false;
    }

    file_put_contents("cachedir/cache.php", get_include_contents("template.php"));

?>
```

To run this you can run the cached file directly, or you can include this on an other page. Like:

```
<?php
    // Variables
    $weather = "fine";

    include("cachedir/cache.php");
?>
```

Comment: it is usefull, but it do cach all parts of page. I want cach some parts of php outputs not all of them.

Comment: You could pass it to a function, include/require it - it's flexible. Of course, you can pass your contents yourself to a cached file, look at fopen() and fwrite() function then - you'll still have to pass the content to them. You can use filemtime() to check the time/date of the file and simply replace it, if it becomes out of date.

Comment: I want use it for flexible templates. I need template that contains multiple parts that was created at different dates. Therefor I need any function that ignore specified php codes section from caching.

Comment: So make that function? You have all the information needed for it, if not please do say. Instead of `echo "myVar";` you can make a function echoBuffer and so use `echoBuffer("myVar");` for contents that must be buffered and make a function that returns your needs. (in this case is should return a (buffered) string "myVar". You can use them both; like echo, date, other functions etc.

Comment: You could also simply `echo '<?php' . date() . '?>';` to your new template file, maybe that is what your looking for?

Comment: your answer is partially correct. But I want make flexible temlate file. For example `<? startcach();echo "some";stopCach();echo date();startcach(); echo "remains";?>` must be cached in files as: `some <? echo date(); ?> remains`

Comment: I modified my answer, hope this is what your looking for.

Comment: that is very close to my question. But it is about reading of any cached file. But I need making (creating) .php cached file. then included cached file run as template.

Comment: I've added the code, please look at some manuals too ;) i named them all before, but this may give you a headstart to understand. Make sure the cachedir map is writable (chmod 757).