# PHP How to not cache generated HTML but cache static data like images/js/css

Tags: javascript, php, css, image, caching

Many PHP developers add the no-cache header on top of their PHP pages, so do I, for obvious reasons. Since PHP generated content is usually dynamic, having the browser cache them results in outdated data being presented to the user. To avoid this caching is usually disabled.

```
<?php
    //no  cache headers 
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1990 05:00:00 GMT");
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

The problem is that due to this header, also my images, javascript files and css files, which are static and thus could (and should) be cached, are also not being cached. This slows down the site a lot.

Is there a way to have no cache on the PHP content, but still have cached js/images/css?

How can this be achieved, assuming I have full access to modify the (linux) server config, HTACCESS and of course, the PHP files themselves?

Or is the whole "no-cache thing" unnecessary for dynamic PHP files? Even when they are url-rewritten to appear extension-less.

Comment: Already you have `header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1990 05:00:00 GMT");` right?

Comment: Yes, as I posted, why?

Comment: Sorry I got confused. Don't mind my comment!

Comment: maybe this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968847/php-partial-caching

Comment: @GillesLesire Check this out maybe? http://www.askapache.com/hacking/speed-site-caching-cache-control.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a htaccess to define files that you want to be cached
all you want is to make a .htaccess file in the main directory of your website and add this code

example:

```
# cache images/pdf docs for 1 week
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public, must-revalidate"
  Header unset Last-Modified
</FilesMatch>

# cache html/htm/xml/txt diles for 2 days
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I think he is aware of that he just want's to do it using php.

Comment: Yes I already do it like this but it feels hacky. I was just wondering if a cleaner way exists.

Answer (score 2):

I Might be wrong but I beleive you can bring all your js and CSS files into a single php and then cache that using something like

```
ob_start ("ob_gzhandler");
ob_start("compress");
```

So you would have a .php the defines its header then a few requires on your js and css file's and also the above.

You will probobly need a couple of if statements to pickup changes etc.

I will make a more comprehensive answer in a few I am on my phone at the moment.

---

**UPDATE**

Found a resource on git that I think will help set you in the right path.

https://github.com/SubZane/CSS-Compressor/blob/master/csscompressor.php

Comment: Thanks, combining those static files will speed up a lot and was also something I was looking into. This might fix all those issues at once. I'll definitely look into this.

Comment: Good Glad your sorted mate.

Comment: Your solution works for js and css files but for images I guess I'll still have to use mohamed amin's solution.

Comment: Let me have a think about images and get back to you